# What to return if a method returns an interface?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I am given a set of interfaces and have to create a class that implements these interfaces, however, I am confused about the return type for the interfaces that have references to other interfaces.

// Implement class C below so that the code compiles. None of the methods may return null.
    // You may define supplementary classes (inner-classes or "regular" classes) if you wish.
    // Note that C is a subclass of Object, and it implements only X and Y -- you cannot change this.

```
abstract class A {
abstract void q ();
}

interface Y {
int p (int j);
A me ();
}

interface X {
void m (Object o);
X n ();
}

class C implements X, Y {
// Write your code here -- make all methods public (otherwise,
// the compiler will not consider the interfaces to be "implemented")!

    @Override
public int p(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public A me() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void m(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public X n() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

What am I suppose to return for the methods that have an interface for a return type? I am confused because you can't instantiate interfaces so what am I suppose to return?

Comment: You return the instanciation of a class that implements the interface. For example, the `List` interface is implemented by `ArrayList`, among others. If a method returns a `List`, returning an `ArrayList` is a valid solution.

Comment: Non of my classes implements the A class though.

Comment: You can give a reference to an interface if you create an anonymous class. `Runnable run = new Runnable() { }`. The methods from your interface will be stored in your variable. This isnt instiansiating an interface, rather giving the methods contained in your interface some kind of reference.

Comment: I notice that `A` is an abstract class, so your class `C` may have to extend it. Also to note, I don't know what the code of the methods is supposed to do, but it is possible to do a `return this;`, since your class `C` implements the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a class which implements the interface and return an object of that class.

As your question says: `You may define supplementary classes`, so just write the classes that implement those interfaces. In the case of `abstract` classes, you must extend those.

```
class Foo extends A {
// Override abstract method
}
```

Since class `C` already implements `X` and `Y`, you can just return an object of class C (`new C()`), where either `X` or `Y` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a reference to an interface if you create an anonymous class. Runnable run = new Runnable() { }. The methods from your interface will be stored in your variable. This isnt instiansiating an interface, rather giving the methods contained in your interface some kind of reference.

```
public Runnable run() {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() { }
    };
}
```

This also applies for abstract classes. Usually, you cant directly create an instance of an abstract class `new A();`, but anonymous classes allow you to create a subclass of a sort, that allows you to override the methods that require a body. Creating an anonymous class is similar to creating a subclass in some ways. You have access to protected variables, and can also declare new methods.

If your interface only contains 1 method, you cpuld also use lambda expressions

```
Runnable run = () -> {

}
```

Comment: I created an inner class Z that extends the abstract class A and then created in instance of Z and returned it and that seems to work?

Comment: You were asking about a method that has the return type of an interface. If you extend a class, you inherit it's type. `class Z extends A { }` `A obj = new Z()` makes total sense, so if return type was A, you could return a Z instance. This also works with interfaces whe  implementing them. I was just showing how you could return a value when the methods return type is an interface

Comment: The first method (creating an anonymous class) works for abstract classes as well as for interfaces.  (But lambdas don't.)

Comment: @ajb The lambda was made with intentions of returning `run`, rather than returning a value imediately as I did in my method example

Comment: I think you misunderstood me... your examples are perfectly fine.  I was just pointing out that your first solution, which you're using to create an anonymous class that implements an interface, could *also* be used to create anonymous class that extends an abstract class, which could be useful for the OP's question.

Comment: @ajb Oh, I understand now. Sorry about that, and thanks for pointing out the abstract class part. I thought he was only worried about interfaces. Ill update my answer